# Quickest way to get a landing page

Tags: 7

What is the quickest way to create a landing page for Drupal 7? The [landing page](http://drupal.org/project/landing_pages) module is currently not available for drupal 7. What sort of modules should I use?

Comment: what content do you want to show on those landing pages?

Comment: an image, few lines of text at most.

Comment: I would just use the "basic page" content type and embed your image in the text or add a "photo" field to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the content: Use an approriate content type or view.
2. For the URL use an URL alias to get something like www.mysite.com/landingpage .
3. If you want to hide some blocks on the landing page add a PHP snippet in the block configuration which queries `arg()` or `$_GET['q']` for the URL.
4. If you need an other theme have a look at the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.
5. Use the [Nodewords: D6 Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module to add meta tags for SEO or Facebook open graph tags.
6. Use the statistics or [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module to track the succses of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a node or a view with a page display. Configure site information and set the path of previous item as default front page.

Comment: I don't think OP means how can they create a front page.  I think it's more about how can you create a PPC (or other) landing page.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module? You can force users to log-in first and then you can redirect them to where ever you want!